# Local notification repeatinterval every Tuesday not working.. what am I missing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification, repeat

So, I understood that monday is `= 2` now when I say tuesaday is `= 3` it won't fire.

either I'm not setting the day correctly or the `NSWeekCalendarUnit` for the `calendar components` and the `repeatinterval` is wrong!

now my wonders are:
is the `day components` are equal to `1` till `7` starting with sundays?

also, should it be an `NSDayCalendarUnit` or I'm doing it right?

take a look at my code and see if you can fix it. Thanks

```
-(void) tuesday {   // every tuesday
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

components.day = 1;
components.hour   = 18;
components.minute = 55;
components.second = 45;

NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"Tuesday %@", fireDate);

UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;
if (notif == nil)
    return;

notif.fireDate = fireDate;
notif.repeatInterval= NSWeekCalendarUnit ;
notif.soundName = @"ring.wav";
notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello World"] ;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif] ;
}
```

Update:

Here is the log I'm getting:

```
2014-01-19 18:55:09.258 daily notification test[14609:c07] Tuesday 0001-01-01 18:55:45 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be, that you add your components to an NSDate, without setting the relevant date parameters. To fire your notification, you'll need to define the NSDate for the next tuesday.

Hope this example helps you a bit:

```
//first you have to check what's the current weekday
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

//Set timezone if needed
gregorian.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
int currentWeekday = [comps weekday] ;
NSLog(@"currentWeekDay:%d", currentWeekday);


//After you know which weekday it is, you can check how many days to add till tuesday

int daysToAdd;
switch (currentWeekday) {
        //Sunday to Tuesday
    case 1:
        daysToAdd = 2;
        break;

        //Monday to Tuesday
    case 2:
        daysToAdd = 1;
        break;

        //Tuesday to Tuesday
    case 3:
        daysToAdd = 0;
        break;

        //Wednesday to Tuesday
    case 4:
        daysToAdd = 6;
        break;

        //Thursday to Tuesday
    case 5:
        daysToAdd = 5;
        break;

        //Thursday to Tuesday
    case 6:
        daysToAdd = 4;
        break;

    case 7:
        daysToAdd = 3;
        break;

    default:
        daysToAdd = 0;
        break;
}

NSDate *firetime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *timeCorrection = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[timeCorrection setHour:18];
[timeCorrection setMinute:55];
[timeCorrection setSecond:45];
firetime = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:timeCorrection toDate:firetime options:0];

NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:daysToAdd];
firetime = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:firetime options:0];

//this should be your fire date
NSLog(@"Next tuesday:%@",firetime);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for, or gives you the right hint. Haven't tested.

greetz,
Zarakas